# Changing system icon in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm doing an app for windows written in `C#`. 
I want the app to change the icon of the trash icon / recycle bin. 
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm sure you'll have to use some Win32Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the recycle bin icon is defined in the registry of Windows.

This page show exactly where: http://www.winxptutor.com/rbicon.htm

I'll copy it here as mirror just in case:

> The Recycle Bin icon is defined in two
>   places in the registry:
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\
>   CLSID\
>   {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\
>   DefaultIcon
>
> and
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\
>   Software\
>   Microsoft\
>   Windows\
>   CurrentVersion\
>   Explorer\
>   CLSID\
>   {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\
>   DefaultIcon

By default, the values point to system DLL with the default icon. (Different in each Windows version)

So all you need is overwriting the registery values for the names `(Default)`, `empty` and `full` in the above two locations to your own DLL with your own icon and the icon should change.

Writing to regisry with `C#` should be simple, if you need further help let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the moment i'm testing with location number 2 (HKEY_CURRENT_USER...) which works when manually editing in regedit. Do I have to change both locations?

Comment: @s0mmer yes looks like you'll have to change both and restart the computer for this to take effect..

Comment: I think this is a general (Windows 7?) issue, but when I change the Recycle Bin icon (even in the Windows settings) i have to refresh the desktop before i can see it change state (empty->full and vice versa..). I've also tried to delete the IconCache.. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @s0mmer - sorry no good idea ATM. But I think that restart a is valid option as you're changing something in the very "core" of Windows. (It might be small thing, but still - part of the core)

Answer (score 0):

See there in regedit also:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}]
```